# Move ggplot2 gridlines to top layer but keep panel background

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

Using the `sf` package with `ggplot2`, gridlines are used to draw graticules. By setting `panel.ontop` to `TRUE`, it is possible to have the graticules on top of the map:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = nc, fill='white') +
    coord_sf(expand = T) +
    theme(panel.border = element_rect(color = 'black', fill = NA),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          panel.ontop = T,
          plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#ddefff"),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank()) +
    ggtitle("NC")
```

[image]

What I would like, however, is to be able to set the background color of the plot area, which would usually be done with `panel.background`. This obviously won't work here, as it would cover the map.

Desired result:

[image]

My initial thoughts are that I could first add a `geom_rect` the exact size of the panel area, but I am not sure how I would get those dimensions. How can I keep the gridlines on top, but still have a unique panel background color?

**Edit**

Adding on to the good answer from @sebdalgarno below, I found we can address the expansion problem using `expand_range` (as `ggplot2` does internally):

```
bb <- st_bbox(nc)
bb[c(1,3,2,4)] <- c(scales::expand_range(c(bb$xmin, bb$xmax), mul = 0.05),
                    scales::expand_range(c(bb$ymin, bb$ymax), mul = 0.05))
bb <- bb %>% st_as_sfc() %>% st_sf()
```

This now gives the same expansion factor as if `coord_sf(expand = T)` were set.

Comment: do you need expand = T? if not (i.e. expand = F), I can provide an answer

Comment: I would like `expand = T` to be an option because for some of the maps I am making it looks strange if the borders go all the way to the edge. I could work around this though, so if you have an answer without it I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution works with expand = F:

Following on your geom_rect suggestion turn the bbox into a sf polygon

```
bb <- st_bbox(nc) %>% st_as_sfc() %>% st_sf()
```

and plot with geom_sf

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = bb, fill = 'grey') +
  geom_sf(data = nc, fill='white') +
  coord_sf(expand = F) +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(color = 'black', fill = NA),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.ontop = T,
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#ddefff"),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank()) +
  ggtitle("NC")
```

If you can figure out how to manually expand the bbox polygon by the same amount, this could work with expand = T

[image]

Comment: Thanks that works great! See my edit for how I addressed the expand issue.